# scroll to child element horizontally on click (ion-scroll)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to create a scrollable horizontal navigation bar, using ion-scroll.

When you click an element of the navigation bar, ion-scroll should scroll horizontally to that element so it becomes fully into view.

Here's the navigation bar. As you can see I have clicked on the "Help" section but it's outside the screen.

[image]

The HTML is as follows (login.html):

```html
<ion-navbar class="h_nav_toolbar">
  <ion-scroll scrollX="true" id="h_nav_scroller">
    <div class="h_nav_container">
      <ul class="h_nav">
        <li id="login_tab" (click)="show_section('login')" [class.active]="current_section == 'login'">Login</li>
        <li id="register_tab" (click)="show_section('register')" [class.active]="current_section == 'register'">Register</li>
        <li id="forgot_password_tab" (click)="show_section('forgot_password')" [class.active]="current_section == 'forgot_password'">Forgot Password?</li>
        <li id="help_tab" (click)="show_section('help')" [class.active]="current_section == 'help'">Help</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-navbar>
```

And the Typescript (login.ts)

```js
show_section(section_id){
  this.current_section = section_id;

  let section_element = document.getElementById(section_id + '_tab');
  section_element.scrollIntoView(true);

}
```

Unfortunately, my current attempt does not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: My status on this issue: It seems ion-scroll can’t be scrolled programmatically, even when using native JS (scrollLeft). I think some ugly workaround could be done, maybe using transform:translateX (?) but I thought spending more time debugging was more trouble than what it’s worth. If someone finds a solution, do let me know!

Comment: anybody found a solution for this ?

Comment: have you solved? I have the same issue. Thanks